# Undefined method 'e=' for #<OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x00563aaff72138>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, net-sftp

I'm trying to download file from Heroku's SFTP To Go using net/sftp gem but I always get undefined method `e=' for #.

Been searching online but can't find any related solutions. Here is my code:

```
task employer_email_import: :environment do
  require 'net/sftp'
  require 'uri'

  sftptogo_url = ENV['SFTPTOGO_URL']
  uri = URI.parse(sftptogo_url)

  Net::SFTP.start(uri.host, uri.user, :password => uri.password) do |sftp|
     sftp.download!("some_directory", "some_directory")
  end

end
```

**Error:**
undefined method `e=' for #< OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x00563aaff72138>
Did you mean?  e**********

"/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:255:in `read_keyblob'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:239:in`read_key'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:145:in `block (2 levels) in keys_for'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:127:in`each_line'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:127:in `block in keys_for'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:125:in`open'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:125:in `keys_for'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:55:in`block in search_in'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:55:in `map'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:55:in`search_in'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/known_hosts.rb:49:in `search_for'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:96:in`host_keys'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb:251:in `prepare_preferred_algorithms!'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb:124:in`initialize'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:86:in `new'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:86:in`initialize'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:232:in `new'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:232:in`start'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp.rb:31:in `start'", "/home/romz/Desktop/Romz/site/ROR/recoverysuite/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:376:in`block (2 levels) in '", "/home/romz/Desktop/Romz/site/ROR/recoverysuite/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:353:in `each'", "/home/romz/Desktop/Romz/site/ROR/recoverysuite/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:353:in`block in '", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in`each'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in`invoke_with_call_chain'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in`invoke_task'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in`each'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in`run_with_threads'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in`block in run'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in`run'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:23:in`load'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in`load'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in`run'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:463:in `exec'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in`run'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in`dispatch'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in`start'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/exe/bundle:30:in`block in '", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/exe/bundle:22:in`'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'", "/home/romz/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:23:in`'"

---

RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.4.0"

OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
=> "OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017"

OpenSSL::VERSION
=> "2.0.2"

rails --version
=> Rails 5.0.7.1

Comment: upgrading net-ssh to 4.2 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

use:

```
gem 'net-sftp'

gem 'net-ssh', '~> 5.1.0'

gem 'openssl', '~> 2.0.0.beta.1'
```

this will solve your issue.